# Can I create an Azure Batch pool with a custom image that requires image plan?

Tags: azure, azure-batch

I have created an Azure Batch pool that is configured to allocate VMs from a custom VM image that I have created.
The custom VM image is based on "PyTorch from NVIDIA" which **requires an image plan**.

When the pool tries to allocate nodes it fails on the following error:

> Deployment allocation failed due to missing image plan information in the request. You need to create custom image based on first party image which does not require image plan.

It seems that it's possible to create Virtual Machine Scale Sets with an image plan as indicated by this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachinescalesets/createorupdate#create-a-scale-set-with-a-marketplace-image-plan.). 
Is it possible to create an Azure Batch pool with a custom VM image that requires an image plan? 
The error suggests that it's not possible but that seems very limiting and in contrast to VMSS in which it does seem possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only use a first-party Azure Marketplace image supported by Batch as the base image for your managed image, refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-custom-images#prepare-a-vm).

If your custom VM image is generated from an Azure Marketplace image, you can select the correct `Publisher/Offer/Sku` for your custom image when [you create a pool from a custom image in the portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-custom-images#create-a-pool-from-a-custom-image-in-the-portal).

### Edit

I also can produce this issue when I use a generalized `PyTorch from NVIDIA` VM as the base image. As the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-custom-images#prepare-a-vm) stated, it's impossible to use a third-party image as the base image to create a pool at the moment.

Some VM images in the Azure Marketplace have an additional license and purchase terms that you must accept and provide purchase plan parameters before you can deploy them programmatically.

> You can't use a third-party image that has additional license and
>   purchase terms as your base image. For information about these
>   Marketplace images, see the guidance for [Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/cli-ps-findimage#deploy-an-image-with-marketplace-terms) or Windows VMs.

Comment: Regarding the point you made in the 2nd paragraph that hasn't been my experience. In the portal when you create a pool then you can't specify publisher/offer/sku if you choose a custom vm image, you can only specify those if you specify a marketplace image.

It seems like the UI in the post you linked to is not up-to-date.

Comment: Maybe it's UI change but you need a plan when you deploy a VM from a third-party image. Please check my edit reply.