# Customize a VM image from the shared gallery for use in batch

Tags: azure-batch

I would like to take an image from the Azure shared image gallery, customize it by adding additional software and use it for my batch pool. More specific, I would like to use the Azure batch rendering image for Windows machines and add additionall software. I still need to book the licenses for the preinstalled software through Azure batch.

What I have tried so far:

1. Create a VM using the Azure batch rendering image for Windows from the shared image gallery
2. Create a snapshot from this VM as an image
3. Create my own shared image gallery and add the image to this gallery
4. Create a pool on my batch account, specifing the previously created image from my gallery
5. The result is an error message when resizing the pool to contain a node: "Deployment allocation failed due to missing image plan information in the request. You need to create custom image based on first party image which does not require image plan."

Are there any steps I can take to get this running?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I create an Azure Batch pool with a custom image that requires image plan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59371794/can-i-create-an-azure-batch-pool-with-a-custom-image-that-requires-image-plan)

Comment: @Tats_innit Unfortunately not. We specified the publisher, offer and sku for the image definition in our image gallery, but this did not do the trick...